# Add a user to group docker and such a user can access unauthorized directories in container by mounting directories via -v

Tags: docker, docker-container

In my centos system, I add a user to group docker, and I found such a user can access any folder by attach folder to container via `docker run -it -v path-to-directory:directory-in-container`. For example, I have a folder with mode 700 which can only access by root, but if someone who doesn't have permission to access this folder run a container and mount this folder to container, he can access this folder in container.How can I prevent such a user to attach unauthorized directories to docker container? My docker version is 17.03.0-ce, system os centOS 7.0. Thanks!

Comment: Docker bypasses the default linux permissions. It is mentioned on their documentation. Try setting the user role in docker to restrict him. Follow this documentation link https://docs.docker.com/datacenter/ucp/2.2/guides/access-control/permission-levels/#roles

Answer (score 0):

You should refer and follow the container principles for security or external volume permission setting up. But you want to test simply for container features.
You can set up the path-to-directory access mode 777, yes it's world-readable-writable access mode. It's no additional owner-group setting and access mode setting for any container volume mapping.

```
chmod 777 /path/to/directory
```

Comment: May be you have misunderstood my question. if I have a diretory with mode 700 which only allow root to access. But any user in docker group can access this folder in container via mount this folder by -v. I want to prevent this folder from unauthorized access.

Comment: @linjpthu I'd like to apologize you for my wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

Docker daemon runs as root and normally starts the containers as root, with users inside mapping one-to-one to the host users, so anybody in the `docker` group has effective root permissions.

There is an option to tell dockerd to run the containers via subusers of a specific user, see [https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/]. That prevents full root access, but everybody accessing the docker daemon will be running the containers under that user—and if that user is not them, they won't be able to usefully mount things in their home.

Also I believe it is incompatible with `--privileged` containers, but of course those give you full root access via other means as well anyway.